# What is the proper way of notating all elements in an equation are real?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Assuming `c = a + ib` and `c* = a - ib` where a and b are real
I want to show that `c + c*` is real
To do this I showed
`(c + c*) = a + ib + a - ij = 2a`
but I don't know how to state 2a is real. I'm thinking there is a way to state: "each element in the equation 2a belong to the set of real numbers, therefore c+c* is real" is what I have to say, I just don't know how to put that into proper math notation.

Comment: You can just say "$2a$ is a real number", or you could write "$2a\in\mathbb R$".

Comment: Words do just fine. In addition to Dave's suggestion: you should say that $a$ and $b$ are real when *defining* $c$. It's not like you can decide what $a$ is **after** computing things that depend on it. You could say something like this: "let $a,b \in \Bbb R$ and $c = a+ib$. Then $c+c^\ast = a+ib +a-ib = 2a$."

Comment: Just say it. " $c + c^* = (a+bi) + (a-bi) = 2a$ which is a real number."  Why are you thinking there is something else that needs to be incantated?

Comment: @guidoar the OP *did* say "where a and b are real"

Comment: @fleablood yeah, I meant to say that although we can *emphazise* that $2a$ is real, its not a replacement for defining $a,b \in \Bbb R$ beforehand. My comment is admittedly not very enlightening

Comment: The notation is $a\in \mathbb R$ and therefore $2a \in \mathbb R$.  That's all.  But notation isn't magic.  Using words is perfect acceptable and must mathematicians prefer it.

Comment: Are you asking *why* $2a$ is real?  If so that is because $2$ is real and $a$ is real.  The product of any two reals is a real number.  (We refer to that as saying "The reals are closed under multiplication" which means, literally, the product of any two real numbers is itself a real number).  The reason that is true is because it is an axiom.  (I'm actually no entirely sure what your actual question is; you really do seem to be done with your proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking what is the notation for saying "$M$ is a real number".

The notation is:  $M\in \mathbb R$.

What that means literally is: $\mathbb R$ represents the set of all real numbers.  $\in$ is the symbol indicate "is an element of a set" or "is a member of a set" so $x\in A$ means that $x$ is an element of the set $A$.

So $2a \in \mathbb R$ means that $2a$ is an element of the set of real numbers.  Or..... in plain English, $2a$ is a real number.

But speaking of plain English, it's not clear to me why you think you can't use plain english in your proof.

Your proof is fine as: "$c =a + bi$ and $c^* = a-bi$ where $a,b$ are real numbers and $i$ is the imaginary unit.  So $c+c^* = (a+bi) + (a-bi) = 2a$ which is a real number."

It's good to know the notation $2a\in \mathbb R$ but as you seem to have gone this far without it you could go another day or two without it.

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting each number into real and imaginary parts:

$c=a+ib$

By definition, $a$ and $b$ are real. Hence, the first term on the right side is real, and the second term is imaginary.

So when you get

$c + c^* = a + ib + a - ib = 2a,$

you're done. The value $2a$ is real (because the reals are closed under multiplication).